Could not save in cdo
I've used vimscript to filter out a bunch of .csv files, then, i'd like to insert a line to each of them.
If I copy the content to register a and use
:cdo norm"ap|update|edit#

it always report an error:

E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)

Did I miss anything?
Currently I work around it via
:cdo call append(line('.'), 'Text to insert') | update | edit #

But i'm curious on if there's something I overlooked or this is a bug...

What if you do: :cdo norm"ap|update|buffer#?

you need to do :cdo :exe 'norm!"ap'|upd|ed#

@ChristianBrabandt may I ask what does the exclamation mark do?

@athos it prevents mappings in the command, so it does what you expect even if you map quote, a, and/or p

The :normal command eats all its arguments. You can use :execute to prevent that, as Christian mentions in the comments.
Or stick to Ex:
:cdo put a | update | edit #

Though I’m not sure why you’d want to :edit # in a cdo loop.

I would do:
:cdo call append(line('.'), 'Text to insert') | buffer #
:cfdo update | buffer #

The idea is to save the buffers once for every buffer and not for every changes.
